# XForms: get the position of item in model using select element

Tags: xforms

I'm really struggling with XForms.  This code has two problems.  My refresh action doesn't work and my `position()` value doesn't work.  I can't find any documentation that specifies which elements are allowed/need to be nested within each other. It seems like XForms has a huge amount of capability but I can't get anything to hook up.  This is just supposed to set "sel" to 2.  I've also tried "value="instance('foo')/bar[index('ns')]/position()" " because I'm not sure if only ref attributes inherit a context node.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
<body>
    <xf:model id="master">
        <xf:instance xmlns="" id="test">
            <foo>
                <bar>test</bar>
                <bar>error</bar>
                <sel>1</sel>
            </foo>
        </xf:instance>
    </xf:model>
    <xf:output ref="sel"/>
    <xf:select1 id="sl" ref="instance('test')/sel">
        <xf:itemset id="ns" nodeset="instance('test')/bar[.='error']">
            <xf:label ref="."/>
            <xf:value value="./position()"/>
        </xf:itemset>
        <xf:action>
            <xf:refresh model="master"/>
        </xf:action>
    </xf:select1>
</body>
</html>
```

Any literature on the rules and categories of all the XForms elements would also be appreciated.  `http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/` sure makes it look like a `select` element and a `trigger` element are similar things.  But if they are, why does my refresh work inside a `trigger` but not a `select`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, the position() function is evaluated according to the selected list of nodes and, in this example, there is just one element because of the predicate. It is possible to use the count() function as in "count(preceding-sibling::bar)+1".

About the action, an ev:event attribute is required to tell when the action is to be performed.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I had to set incremental to true in order to see what I was expecting.  And the count function works as well.  If you don't mind, why do I need to reference a preceding sibling and then add one?  I wouldn't have ever figured that out.

Answer (score 1):

A few notes on your code:

- Usually, XForms models are placed under the HTML `head` element, although implementations are allowed to place models in other places.
- I cannot see how your code can set the value of `sel` to `2` because you are going to have a dropdown control with a single item with label "error" and value `2`. But there is no code which sets the value of `sel` to `2`. And that's because the value would change only if the user changes the selected value in the dropdown, but the user cannot do that because there is only one item.
- In XForms, you very rarely need an explicit `refresh` action. The view is automatically refreshed after changes to the data model have completed.
- Yes, a `trigger` is like a `select1`: a [core form control](http://www.w3.org/TR/xforms/#controls).
- All XForms actions need to tell which event they react to with the `ev:event` attribute (or plain `event` with some implementations). Your `action` action doesn't have an `ev:event` attribute so wouldn't run anyway.
- XForms now recommends using `ref` consistently instead of `nodeset`. Some implementations already support that.
- the `position()` XPath expression is sometimes tricky because it only works following the XPath context position. With Orbeon, using `position()` as you show works. But if it doesn't, you could also try to compute the position using `count(preceding::bar) + 1`.

The following works with Orbeon, in the sense that I have made your itemset point to the two `bar` elements, and if the user changes the selection, the value in `sel` changes. There is no need for an explicit action or refresh, because the dropdown will write its value to the `sel` element as it changes.

```
<html
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xf="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms">
    <head>
        <xf:model id="master">
            <xf:instance xmlns="" id="test">
                <foo>
                    <bar>test</bar>
                    <bar>error</bar>
                    <sel>1</sel>
                </foo>
            </xf:instance>
        </xf:model>
    </head>
    <body>
        <xf:output ref="sel"/>
        <xf:select1 id="sl" ref="sel">
            <xf:itemset id="ns" nodeset="instance('test')/bar">
                <xf:label ref="."/>
                <xf:value value="position()"/>
            </xf:itemset>
        </xf:select1>
    </body>
</html>
```